# jQuery - find y-position of top of window in vertically scrollable document

Tags: jquery, offset

I have a document that is very tall and gets scrolled vertically. I would like at a certain time to detect what the visible area is in relation to the full document.

So if `$('body').height()` is 6000 and when my function triggers they are scrolled 2/3 of the way through, I would like to be able to get back the number `4000`.

I know this is simple, I just cant figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('body').scrollTop()`

> The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that
>   are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is
>   at the very top, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will
>   be 0.

from [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use  `$(window).scrollTop()` instead of $('body').scrollTop().

Some browsers don't behave properly when 'body' is utilized, but using 'window' I never had such problems